# Add/Remove individual widgets from gridster

Tags: gridster

I'm trying to add and or remove a a widget based on a button click function. It works but once the function is called once it does something odd where the code is called on any mouse click instead of just the button click on the html page. So if I click the remove button on the html page it will remove that widget but then if I click any other widget (not on a button) it still removes that widget. I only want the function called on the html button click, not any mouse click. It's like the button is initializing something on the page to make any mouse click call the remove function. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it? My code below:

```
function deleteWidget() {
    var gridster = $('.gridster ul').gridster().data('gridster');
    $(document).on( "click", ".gridster ul li", function() {
        $(this).addClass("activ");
        gridster.remove_widget($('.activ'));
    });
    }

    function addWidget() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
    $(document).on("click", ".gridster ul li", function() {      
        gridster.add_widget('<li class="gs_w">The HTML of the widget...</li>', 2, 1);
    });
    }

<li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"><button onclick="addWidget()" style="float: right;">+</button><h3>4</h3><span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>
<li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"><button onclick="deleteWidget()"style="float: right;">-</button><h3>6</h3></li>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on your delete button, your code is creating a bind that makes any click on any widget, run the code to remove it.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".gridster ul li", function() {
        $(this).addClass("activ");
        gridster.remove_widget($('.activ'));
    });
```

You can try change your html to:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"><button class="delete-button" style="float: right;">+</button><h3>4</h3><span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>
<li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"><button class="add-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>6</h3></li>
```

and, in your javascript code, after initializing your gridster add:

```
$(document).on( "click", ".gridster .delete-button", function() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
    gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});

$(document).on("click", ".gridster .add-button", function() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');      
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="gs_w">The HTML of the widget...</li>', 2, 1);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you! I was able to figure out the add widget but was still stuck on deleting it. This worked great. For adding I went with this :                                                                   function addWidget() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');  
        gridster.add_widget('<li class="gs_w">The HTML of the widget...</li>', 2, 1);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Below is the jQuery and HTML required for adding a widget to a gridster grid.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li>new</li>', 1, 2]);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="addWidgetButton" style="float: right;">+</button>
```

Comment: Sorry i thought it was self explanitory,the top part is Jquery and the bottom part is html ,in its simplest form to help people :-)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I tried to beautify your answer a little bit. I hope my edit is ok for you.